# How to bind nginx-ingress to public IP with minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress

My dev environment is a public facing VM with minikube installed. I would like to expose my application thru nginx-ingress to internet. Do I have the wrong expectation with minikube? As I can see minikube doesn't bind the ingress to public IP.

Is this something minikube can do or I need to switch to something like microk8s?

Please advise.

Thank you

Aaron

Comment: are you using Nginx ingress controller installed on the minikube cluster?

Comment: Have you followed the ngnix ingress controller https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/ for minikube? Its different from other installations

Comment: @MickeyHovel yes exactly

Comment: @DannyEbbers i followed the exact tutorial and am able to do "curl hello-world.info" locally and get "hello world" as expected. My goal is to access to this service via my public ip. When I run netstat -nlp I don't see anything running on port 80 as I understand ingress is bond to minikube ip right now instead of the node.

Comment: can you try to ```kubectl port-forward --address  0.0.0.0 pod/<podname>  <external port>:<internal port>``` after you try that try to access the public IP with the specific port

Comment: Hi, what platform / infrastructure are You running Your `minikube` cluster on? In most cases You will need a load balancer like `MetalLB` to provision external IP to Your ingress.